# Android Studio's debugger never attaches

Tags: android, debugging, adb

So I've been using the debugger quite a bit with the project I'm working on (upwards of a month) without too much in the way of issues. Now all of the sudden, the debugger stopped working. I can still run the application on either one of the two devices I'm using to test, but when I try to debug them I get the little popup "waiting for debugger to attach" without it ever resolving. I haven't upgraded or otherwise changed the configuration, does anyone know what might be causing this?

Update: when I try to quit Android Studio it asks to detach from the process, then tries to do so and gives me an endless progress bar. So I guess it thinks it's still connected to the process (spoiler: it's not, both my devices are unplugged). What do??

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting then reconnecting your device?

Comment: Yep, several times and the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know what the problem was. I force quit Android Studio and rebooted my laptop and now it seems to work again. Case closed.

Comment: Same here - I need to reboot laptop - happens at least once a day :(